# Hilbert Symbols (History)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, math-history, p-adic-number-theory

Usually the Hilbert symbol $\left(\frac{a,b}{p}\right)$ is defined via the solvability of $z^2=ax^2+by^2$ in the $p$-adic numbers. Obviously, this can not have been Hilberts original definition, because $p$-adic numbers were only invented later. (And I guess solubility in the $p$-adics is not the same as solubility modulo $p$, right?) What was the original definition?

Answer (score 4):

See [Hilbert symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_symbol) :

> The Hilbert symbol was introduced by David Hilbert in his *Zahlbericht* (1897), with the slight difference that he defined it for elements of global fields rather than for the larger local fields.

For English translation, see David Hilbert, [The Theory of Algebraic Number Fields (1897)](https://books.google.it/books?id=EDrvCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA120), §64 **The Symbol** $(\dfrac {n,m}{w})$, page 120.

Comment: So what is the effect of this changed definition? There is the product formula $\Pi_p (a,b)_p=1$ which seems to hold for either definition. But the values themselves can be different for $F_p$ and $Q_p$?

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't think that your chronological objection (concerning $\mathbf Q_p$, Hensel and Hilbert) is founded: 1897 was the year of birth of the $p$-adics, but also the year of publication of Hilbert's *Zahlbericht*. As the preeminent mathematician of his time, Hilbert had certainly been aware of Hensel's work.

Second, in spite of not being an expert in the history of number theory, I feel reasonably assured that the origin of the Hilbert symbol must be traced back to the Legendre symbol and Gauss' quadratic reciprocity law. Recall that, for a prime $p$ not dividing $d$, by definition $(\frac d p) =+1$ if $d$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, $-1$ if not, and for two distinct prime numbers $p$ and $q$, $(\frac p q)(\frac q p)$=$(-1)^{ (p-1)(q-1)/4}$. The arguments $d,p$ are in $\mathbf Z$ and the value of the symbol decides whether $d$ is a square in $\mathbf F_p^*$. This is the "residual part" of the theory.

The "local part" introduces the Hilbert symbol $(a,b)_p$ which you cite, with arguments $a,b \in\mathbf Q_p^*$. By definition $(a,b)_p = +1$ if  the quadratic form $z^2-ax^2-by^2$ represents $0$ in $\mathbf Q_p$ (i.e. admits a non zero isotropic vector), $-1$ if not. The point is that the Hilbert symbol can be *explicitly* given in terms of Legendre symbols.  The most important application is a classification of finite dimensional non degenerate quadratic forms over $\mathbf Q_p$. If such a form is written in diagonal form, with coefficients $a_1,..., a_n$, it is characterized up to equivalence by three invariants: its dimension $n$; its discriminant $\delta:=\prod a_i$ (viewed in $\mathbf Q_p^*/{\mathbf Q_p^*}^2$ ); a third invariant defined as $\epsilon:=\prod (a_i,a_j)_p$, for all pairs $i<j$.

In the "passage from local to global", it is absolutely necessary to introduce $\mathbf R$, sometimes denoted $\mathbf Q_\infty$, which must be set on the same footing as all the $\mathbf Q_p$'s, with a Hilbert symbol $(a,b)_\infty$ defined analogously. The generic notation for $p$ and $\infty$ is $v$, called a "place" of $\mathbf Q$, and the "product formula" $\prod (a,b)_v=1$ (where $v$ runs over all the places of $\mathbf Q$) is the generalization of the quadratic reciprocity law. The most important result about quadratic forms over $\mathbf Q$ is the Hasse-Minkowski theorem: Let $f$ be a non degenerate quadratic form with coefficients in $\mathbf Q$. Then $f$ represents $0$ in $\mathbf Q$ iff, for all places $v$, $f_v$ (obtained by considering the coefficients as living in $\mathbf Q_v$) represents $0$ in $\mathbf Q_v$. For all these results see e.g. Serre's "A course in Arithmetic", chap. 3-4.

NB: $(\pm 1)$ is no other than the group $\mu_2$ of square roots of unity. For a number field $K$ containing the group $\mu_n$ of $n$-th roots of unity, one can define local Hilbert symbols $(.,.)_v$ taking values in $\mu_n$. This is the starting point of the so-called "explicit reciprocity laws" in class-field theory. See e.g. Cassels-Fröhlich, "Algebraic Number Theory", exercises 1-2 of the appendix (not elementary).